# Generate code for generic nested class with Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, generics, nested, reflection.emit

I'm trying to generate code using Reflection.Emit which would look identical or similar to what C# compiler generates for this:

```
public interface Function<in T, out Res>
{
    Res Apply(T p);
}


public class MyMain<A>
{
    class Closure : Function<A, A>
    {
        public A Apply(A p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

My code works fine if I use some real type, but when I replace it with generic, I get BadImageFormatException.

```
    private static void CreateGenericClosures()
    {
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("genericClosure");
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name, assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

        TypeBuilder main = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Main", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);

        Type t = typeof (Foo);

        // Defining generic param for Main class
        GenericTypeParameterBuilder[] generics = main.DefineGenericParameters("A");
        // t = generics[0]; // [1] Uncomment to enable for nested class

        var iFunctionType = typeof (Function<,>).MakeGenericType(t, t);

        TypeBuilder closure = main.DefineNestedType("Closure", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.NestedPrivate, typeof (object));
        closure.AddInterfaceImplementation(iFunctionType);

        MethodBuilder applyMethod = closure.DefineMethod("Apply",
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.Public,
            CallingConventions.Standard);
        applyMethod.SetParameters(t);
        applyMethod.SetReturnType(t);

        ILGenerator body = applyMethod.GetILGenerator();
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
        body.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        closure.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

        closure.CreateType();
        main.CreateType();

        assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyName.Name + ".dll", PortableExecutableKinds.Required32Bit, ImageFileMachine.I386);
    }
```

Uncomment [1] to see the exception.
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: What does PEVerify say about your assembly?

Comment: I can't run PEVerify on that assembly because it throws exception before assembly is saved.I checked how mono C# compiler handles this case and it calls DefineGenericParameters on nested type. So if I do that it works fine, but not clear why this is required and do I need to match generic types names or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that nested classes don't actually have access to their parents' generic type parameters/arguments and to be well-formed they actually need to redeclare all of the generic type parameters of their parents (see e.g. [this old blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/haibo_luo/nested-types-in-generic-classes), or section I.10.7.1 of the [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), which goes into lots of detail about the requirements for CLS compatibility).  So what you need to do is something like this:

```
...
var t = closure.DefineGenericParameters("A")[0];
var iFunctionType = typeof(Function<,>).MakeGenericType(t, t);
closure.AddInterfaceImplementation(iFunctionType);
...
```

You've still got some other problems (e.g. your IL for the apply method isn't valid), but this should at least unblock you enough to use PEVerify.